# Can I restore deleted data on a database?

Tags: sql, database

I recently deleted some rows in a database using SQL and now I want those rows back, how can I get them back?

I tried using CONTROL+Z

Comment: Do you keep backups of your database? If the answer is no, then the answer is also no (you can't get them back). Databases aren't a Spreadsheet, you can't "undo" a process you've just committed.

Comment: Which database (DBMS)  are you using?

Comment: You might be able to get them back using a log querying tool. I used to use one on DB2 many years ago, but I don't know about such tools for more modern DBs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do so unless you are using the rollback or commit command.